# Printing inode info from grep

Tags: linux, bash

I'm currently learning Linux, and some of the practice I've has me absolutely stumped. 
I'm trying to look for a file in the current directory with particular text, and output its inode number. 
I can confidently do all these things individually but it keeps falling apart when I try to put them together;

```
 find. -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -r "#include" -ls -i
```

but for some reason it just outputs the file names?

Any ideas?

Comment: Would `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -r "#include" | ls -i` bring you any closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: if `maxdepth` is not important, you can just do `grep -r` to recursively search the directory. If it is, use `exec` with `find` as in the 1st answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -exec grep '#include' {} \; -printf '%p %i\n'
```

or grep -q to hide grep output

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q '#include' {} \; -printf '%p %i\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `grep` in recursive mode `-r` - you don't actually need `find` command:

**grep** + **xargs** approach:

```
grep -rl '#include' | xargs -I {} ls -i '{}'
```

An approximate output (`<inode> <filename>`):

```
1837827 test/1.pdb
1712970 2_clean.pdb
1837846 test2/2.pdb
1712965 1_clean.pdb
```

Comment: I assume that grep requires a filename or data via stdin.

Comment: @Cyrus, explain your phrase

Answer (score 0):

Since your search is limited to the current directory, if you don't care about dot files, you can do this more simply with `grep -l`, [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and a wildcard (`*`):

```
ls -i $(grep -ls '#include' *)
```

Output:

```
109057734 file1.txt  109056004 file2.txt  5505834 file3.txt
```

or with older syntax, using backticks instead of `$()`:

```
ls -i `grep -ls '#include' *`
```

Note that I added the `-s` option for **grep** to silence some warnings about grepping directories.

If you want pretty columns, add the `-1` option for **ls**.

```
ls -i1 $(grep -ls '#include' *)
```

Output:

```
109057734 file1.txt
109056004 file2.txt
  5505834 file3.txt
```